# Back-referencing figures

Tags: table-of-contents, back-referencing

Similar to the `backref` package that enables back-referencing for bibliographic items in a LaTeX document, I want to use back-references in my list of figures. Is there a clean way to accomplish this?

EDIT: 
I want to add text behind the caption in the LoF, on what pages a given figure is referenced.

For example:

> 2.3  Visualisation of the manufacturing process (referenced on page 3,4 and 8) ......... 3

Comment: The LoF and LoT are usually furnished with links when using the [hyperref](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package. So this is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: @Thorsten: That is true. A link is already established and when clicked, the view jumps to the corresponding page. I want to insert text behind the caption, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a proof of concept, it do not check for duplicate references on the same page or for two or more ref, etc.  It still need a lot of refinement and protection against active chars, make it work with hyperref, etc.

To use it, put the command `\makefigreflist` in your preamble and use the custom `\figcaption[shortcap]{longcap}{label}` and `\figref{label}` commands. It must be latexed twice.

EDIT 1: Write info direct to output file and made it a little bit more safe

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\newcommand*\figreflistout[1]{}

\newcommand*\makefigreflist{%
    \begingroup
        \makeatletter
        \@input{\jobname.frl}%
        \newwrite\frl@outfile
        \immediate\openout\frl@outfile=\jobname.frl\relax
    \endgroup
    \let\makefigreflist\@empty
    \renewcommand*\figreflistout{%
        \@bsphack
        \begingroup
            \@sanitize
            \@figreflistout}%
    }

\newcommand*\@figreflistout[1]{%
        \protected@write\frl@outfile{}%
            {\string\addtofigreflist{#1}{\thepage}}%
    \endgroup
    \@esphack}

\newcommand*\addtofigreflist[2]{%
    \@ifundefined{frl@#1}%
        {\expandafter\protected@xdef\csname frl@#1\endcsname{#2}}%
        {\expandafter\protected@xdef\csname frl@#1\endcsname{\csname frl@#1\endcsname, #2}}}

\newcommand*\printfigreflist[1]{%
    \@ifundefined{frl@#1}%
        {\ (not referenced)}%
        {\ (referenced on page~\@nameuse{frl@#1})}}

\newcommand\defaultcapt{}

\newcommand\figcaption[3][\defaultcapt]{%
    \renewcommand\defaultcapt{#2}%
    \caption[#1\protect\printfigreflist{#3}]{#2}%
    \label{#3}}

\newcommand\figref[1]{%
    \ref{#1}\figreflistout{#1}}

\makeatother

\makefigreflist

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
    \figcaption{First figure}{fig:01}
    \figcaption{Second figure}{fig:02}
    \figcaption{Third figure}{fig:03}
\end{figure}

\bigskip

In figure \figref{fig:01} and \figref{fig:02} it is..
\clearpage
In figure \figref{fig:01}
\clearpage
In figure \figref{fig:01} and \figref{fig:02} it is..

\end{document}
```

[image]