# Backreferences for equations

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, amsmath, back-referencing, mathtools

I'd like to put a list of pages, hyperlinked to the position of the `\eqref` or `\cref` that point to it in the margin of each `\label`ed equation, like `backref` does for bibliographies and `\cite`.

Both [this answer for `\ref`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37937/2356) and [this one for a figure list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45546/2356) don't support `hyperref` links, deduplication and ranges like `backref`. (*Edit:* see below and first comment, turns out to not be that hard).

*Edit:* so my main problem is displaying text in the margin next to an equation's tag.

*Edit 2:* posted my current solution as an answer

*Edit 3:* It doesn't work with `cleveref` because that patches `\label{X}` in a way that `\df@label` now contains `{X}` instead of just `X` as before which breaks `\refsto`. No idea how that happens, or how I could remove the `{}`. *Edit 4:* actually it's when `amsmath` is loaded before `cleverref`. But it must be loaded before, because `\cref` can't be used to refer to equations otherwise.

*Edit 5:* found a way to remove `{}` if present, is there a builtin command for this?

```
\def\maybeWithBraces{foo} % this
\def\maybeWithBraces{{foo}} % or this
\def\@identity#1{#1}
\def\@@identity#1{\@identity#1}
\edef\withoutBraces{\expandafter\@@identity\maybeWithBraces}
% \withoutBraces→foo in both cases.
```

Comment: Something like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/usage-of-table-figures-shown-in-caption

Comment: Ah yes, turns out getting the backreferences isn't the main problem but putting them next to the equation. Didn't expect that when writing the question, I'll edit it

Answer (score 6):

Found I had to patch `\make@display@tag`, before calling, the current label is in `\df@label`, it's written out and reset there. By storing the label, calling the original and using the label with my `\refsto` I can put backreferences in the margin.

There's no support for ranges like “see p. 2—4” though.

```
\ProvidesPackage{eqbackref}[2013/05/26 v0.1 Backreferences for equations]
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

% dump both reference ends
\newcounter{eqbr@source}
\newcommand{\eqbr@record}[1]{%
    \edef\@l{eqbr\arabic{eqbr@source}}\label{\@l}%
    \if@filesw\protected@write\@auxout{}%
        {\string\eqbr@referenced{#1}{\@l}{\thepage}}\fi%
    \stepcounter{eqbr@source}}

% patch amsmath's eqref
\let\ams@eqref=\eqref
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{%
    \eqbr@record{#1}%
    \ams@eqref{#1}}

% make a list of refering pages
\newcommand{\eqbr@referenced}[3]{%
    \ifinlistcs{#3}{eqbr@page@#1}{}{%
        \listcsxadd{eqbr@page@#1}{#3}%
        \listcsxadd{eqbr@back@#1}{#2}}}

\newcommand{\refsto@prefix}{see p. }
\newcommand{\refsto@delim}{, }
\newcommand{\refsto@suffix}{}
% print list of refering pages
\newcommand{\refsto}[1]{%
    \ifcsundef{eqbr@back@#1}{}{%
        \refsto@prefix%
        \undef\@first%
        \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
            \ifdef\@first{\refsto@delim}{\def\@first{}}%
            \pageref{##1}}%
        \dolistcsloop{eqbr@back@#1}%
        \refsto@suffix}}

\newcommand{\refsto@marginstyle}{\footnotesize\quad}
% patch tag display, show refsto in margin.
\let\ams@make@display@tag=\make@display@tag
% sometimes \df@label expands to `{name}` instead of `name`
\def\@@removebrace@#1{#1}
\def\@@removebrace#1{\@@removebrace@#1}
\renewcommand{\make@display@tag}{%
    \ifdefempty{\df@label}{% can happen with package `autonum`.
        \ams@make@display@tag%
    }{% not empty, show refs
        \edef\orig@label{\expandafter\@@removebrace\df@label}% save label
        \ams@make@display@tag% resets label
        \rlap{\mbox{\refsto@marginstyle\refsto\orig@label}}% show
    }%
}
```

Example use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref} % optional
\usepackage{amsmath} % load before cleveref    
\usepackage{cleveref} % optional
\ussepackage{autonum} % optional
\usepackage{eqbackref}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    E_1 \label{eA} \\
    E_2 \label{eB} \\
    E_3 \label{eC}
\end{align}
\newpage\section{page two}\eqref{eA}
\newpage\section{page three}\eqref{eA}\eqref{eB}\eqref{eB}
\newpage\section{page four}\eqref{eA}
\end{document}
```

Generates:

[image: backrefs in margin]

Comment: This only works for equations defined in `align` environments but not in `equation` environments.