# Reverse figure links

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I like the way that hyperref provides links from references in the text back to figures or equations but at times I'd actually be interested to have the reverse work as well.  Such that figures and equations would link back to where they are mentioned in the text (first mention by default, perhaps).

Is there any existing functionality to create those links or would I need to cook something up myself?

Edit: to clarify, i'm specifically interested in linking from the item itself to a mention in the text rather than from the list of figures to the mention in the text. The idea is to assist someone skimming a paper ("Oh, that graph is interesting. Where do they talk about it"). Once I've taken the time to read the body text of a paper, I've probably already glanced at most of the figures.

Comment: Something like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116046/backreferences-for-equations ?

Comment: That would the sort of thing. I'm still trying to follow what the result of that question was.  There seems to a way to get back references for equations, but it's not clear to me whether they have hyperlinks working from the item to the reference.

Comment: Make a cross-reference to `\ref{x}` in the figure of the image `X.png` is as simpl as use another label for this reference (e.g.  `\ref{x}\label{refx}`) so you can a call it from the caption figure (with `\ref{refx}`). The image itself could be an active hyperlink to  the text `\ref{x}` using  `\hyperref[refx]{\includegraphics{X.png}}`.Or I am missing something?

Comment: @Fran. That seems to work quite nicely.  Thanks! It's not fully automated, but it seems like I should be able to figure out a macro or something for that.

Comment: For figures [Usage of table/figures shown in caption](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14981)