# Problem with refcheck and eqbackref

Tags: labels, refcheck

I tried to use the \eqbackref package mentioned in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116046/backreferences-for-equations?newreg=bfbca06788fc44bda91fdcba0e652c2e). It works pretty well until I combine it with the \refcheck package. If I also load the \refcheck package, then the labels <eqbr0> etc. also appear and sometimes they just overlap with each other, which is a bit annoyting. Actually I don't want them to appear at all. My knowledge is not good enough to modify eqbackref.sty to hide them. So how can I do it? Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{eqbackref}
\usepackage{refcheck}

\begin{document}

\begin{align} \label{eq1}
1
\end{align}
\begin{align} \label{eq2}
1
\end{align}
\eqref{eq1}, \eqref{eq2}.

\end{document}
```

[image]